# Unable to make mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, d3.js, responsive-design

I'm building a world-map in D3.js everything is working perfectly, the only help I require is on the responsiveness the map on different screen size. Here is the link on which I've featured the world map:
https://digitalxlabs.com/animated-banners/worldmap-final.php

Username: DXLdemo
Password: View@098#

Please suggest how shall I update my CSS code to make this work perfectly in responsive mode.

Below is the CSS Files:

---

```
.country:hover {
    stroke: #B3B5B3;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}
span1 {
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
span2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.text {
    font-size:14px;
    text-transform:none;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.point {
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
#container {
    margin-top:20px;
    height: 60.2%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #e8e9e8;
    width:100%;
}
div .fixed {
    position: fixed;
    /*left: 68.9%;
    top: 61.8%;*/


    margin-right:10px;
    right:0;
    width: 23%;
    z-index:1;
    /*opacity:0.9;
    background-color:white;
*/}

div .fixed2{
    position:fixed;

    }

 /*@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (min-device-width: 375px) and (orientation: landscape) {

}*/
 @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
 div .fixed {
 left:75.8%;
 /*top:59%;*/
   }
.white-overlay{
    top:59%;
    }

div#container{
    height:57.2% !important;    
    }

p#manualtip{
    margin-top:16px !important;
    }
.manualtooltip{
    top:18% !important;
    }
.kicker{
    font-size:15px;
    }
}
/* @media screen and (min-device-width: 1280px) and (max-device-width: 1280px) {
div .fixed {
    top:62%;
    margin-right:10px;
}
}*/



/* (1920x1080) Full HD Display */
/*@media screen and (min-device-width: 1680px) and (max-device-width: 1920px) {*/
/* insert styles here */

/*}*/
 /*@media screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {*/
/* insert styles here */
        /*div .fixed {
            top: 74%;
    margin-right: 16px;}

}*/



/*@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation: landscape) {
.buttons-size {
    width: 2em !important;
    height: 2em !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}
#container{
    height: 59%;
}
}*/

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
 .manualtooltip {
    z-index: 11;
    background-color: white;
    right: 0;
    top: 2% !important;
    margin-right: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 3px !important;
    width: 205px !important;
    height: 28%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
.manualheading{
    font-size: 10px !important;
    }
p#manualparatip {
   font-size: 8px !important;
  }
div#closetip {
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 25px !important;
    padding-left: 140px !important;
    margin-top: -38px !important;
}

p#manualtip {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8px !important;
    margin-top: 11px !important;
    color: #056ab5;
}
.atail {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cccccc transparent transparent transparent;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-right: 8px !important;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -13px !important;
}
 .buttons-size {
   width: 2em !important;
   height: 2em !important;
   text-align:center !important;
}
#container{  
   height: 46% !important;
}


div .fixed {
    /* top: 28.1%; */
    left: 20.13% !important;
    width: 79% !important;
}

.kicker {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 48px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
}
. breaks li{
        margin-top: -2px !important;
            }
.white-overlay{
        top: 33% !important;
    height: 16% !important;
    }

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {

      .manualtooltip {
    z-index: 11;
    background-color: white;
    right: 0;
    top: 2% !important;
    margin-right: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 3px !important;
    width: 205px !important;
    height: 28%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
.manualheading{
    font-size: 10px !important;
    }
p#manualparatip {
   font-size: 8px !important;
  }
div#closetip {
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 25px !important;
    padding-left: 140px !important;
    margin-top: -38px !important;
}


.atail {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cccccc transparent transparent transparent;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-right: 8px !important;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -13px !important;
}

      .buttons-size {
    width: 2em !important;
    height: 2em !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}
#container{  
       height: 46% !important;
}
p#manualtip {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 8px !important;
    margin-top: 11px !important;
    color: #056ab5;
}

div .fixed {
    /* top: 28.1%; */
    left: 20.13% !important;
    width: 79% !important;
}
. breaks li{
        margin-top: -2px !important;
            }

.kicker {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 48px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
}

.white-overlay{
        top: 33% !important;
    height: 16% !important;
    }
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
 and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {
    /*  p#manualtip {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    margin-right: 176px !important;
    margin-top: 4px !important;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
    float: right;
}
div .fixed {
    /* top: 28.1%; */
    /*left: 56.13% !important;
    width: 72% !important;
}
.white-overlay {
    top: 62% !important;
    height: 16.5% !important;
}
#container {
    height: 76% !important;
}
ul.breaks{
        margin-left: -24px !important;
    margin-right: 169px !important;
    margin-top: 4px !important;
    }*/

}


 @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
  /* IE10+ specific styles go here
    /* insert styles here */
    .atail {
         margin-right: 24px;
         margin-top: -4px ;
         }
    p#manualtip {
        margin-left: -96px ;
        margin-top:13px; 
        margin-right: 175px ;
        }
    div .fixed{
        width: 35% ;
        left: 73% ;
        }
        .kicker{margin-left: 38px ;}

    /*div .fixed{
        width:25% !important;
        }
    .atail{
        margin-top: -10px 1important;;
        }
    .white-overlay{
        top: 51.5% !important;
        }
    */
}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
div .fixed {
    /*top: 26.1%;*/
    left: 35.13%;
    width: 45%;
    }
.white-overlay{
    background-color: white;

    width: 100%;
    top: 36% !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 8.4% !important;
    }

p#manualtip {
font-size: 10px !important;
float: right !important;
margin-right: -63px !important;
margin-top: 4px !important;
color: #056ab5;
}

.buttons-size {
    width: 2em !important;
    height: 2em !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}
#container{

height: 41% !important;
    }
/*p#manualtooltip{
    font-size:11px !important;
    margin:right:20px !important;
    margin-top:10px !important; 
    }*/
.kicker {
font-size: 10px !important;
    margin-left: 47px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
/* margin-right: 40px; */
margin-top: 5px;
}

.manualtooltip {
z-index: 1;

right: 0;


top: 1.8% !important;
margin-right: 10px;
opacity: 0.9;

width: 209px !important;
height:29% !important;
padding-left: 4px;
margin-bottom: 10px;

background-color: white;
}

.manualheading{
    font-size: 8.5px !important;
    }
p#manualparatip {
font-size: 8.5px !important;
}
div#closetip {
font-size:8px !important; 
right: 0;
margin-right: 25px;
padding-left: 150px !important;
margin-top: -35px !important;
}
.atail{
    margin-right: 13px !important;
          margin-top: -10px !important;
    }
/*ul.breaks{
    margin:4px;
    list-style:initial;
    margin-left:-100px; 
    margin-top:10px;
    }*/
ul.breaks {
margin: 1px !important;
list-style: initial;
margin-left: 8px !important;
margin-right: 3px !important;
/* float: right; */
margin-top: 12px !important;
}
.breaks li{
    float:left;
    height:30px;
    margin 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    position:relative;
    width:15%;  
    }
.bar{
    width:150%;
    height:8px; 
    }
.dtext{
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:9px;  
    }
/*.buttons-size{

    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -webkit-appearance: none; 
}*/
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
div .fixed {
    /*top: 26.1%;*/
    left: 35.13%;
    width: 45%;
    }
.white-overlay{
    background-color: white;

    width: 100%;
    top: 36% !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 8.4% !important;
    }

p#manualtip {
font-size: 10px !important;
float: right !important;
margin-right: 8px !important;
margin-top: 4px !important;
color: #056ab5;
}

.buttons-size {
    width: 2em !important;
    height: 2em !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}
#container{

height: 41% !important;
    }
/*p#manualtooltip{
    font-size:11px !important;
    margin:right:20px !important;
    margin-top:10px !important; 
    }*/
.kicker {
font-size: 10px !important;
margin-left: 47px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
/* margin-right: 40px; */
margin-top: 5px;
}

.manualtooltip {
z-index: 1;

right: 0;


top: 1.8% !important;
margin-right: 10px;
opacity: 0.9;
height:29% !important;
width: 209px !important;

padding-left: 4px;
margin-bottom: 10px;

background-color: white;
}

.manualheading{
    font-size: 8.5px !important;
    }
p#manualparatip {
font-size: 8.5px !important;
}
div#closetip {
font-size:8px !important; 
right: 0;
margin-right: 25px;
padding-left: 150px !important;
margin-top: -35px !important;
}
.atail{
    margin-right: 13px !important;
            margin-top: -10px !important;
    }
/*ul.breaks{
    margin:4px;
    list-style:initial;
    margin-left:-100px; 
    margin-top:10px;
    }*/
ul.breaks {
margin: 1px !important;
list-style: initial;
margin-left: 8px !important;
margin-right: 3px !important;
/* float: right; */
margin-top: 12px !important;
}
.breaks li{
    float:left;
    height:30px;
    margin 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    position:relative;
    width:15%;  
    }
.bar{
    width:150%;
    height:8px; 
    }
.dtext{
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:9px;  
    }
/*.buttons-size{

    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -webkit-appearance: none; 
}*/
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px)
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 
div .fixed {
    /*top: 64%;*/
    left: 62.13%;
width: 52%;

}
.white-overlay{
    top: 70% !important;
    height: 16.5% !important;

    }
.text {
    font-size:10px;
}
#container {
height: 74.2% !important;
}
div#zoombutton{
    top:7% !important;  
    }
.buttons-size {
    width: 2em !important;
    height: 2em !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}
.manualtooltip{
    top: 11% !important;
    width: 216px !important;
    height: 43% !important;
    }
div#closetip{
    margin-top: -38px !important;
    }
.atail{
    margin-top: -8px !important;
    }
p#manualtip{
    font-size: 10px !important;
margin-right: 106px !important;
margin-top: 5px !important;
margin-left: -13px;
float: right;
    }
.kicker{
    font-size: 10px !important;
margin-left: 16px !important;
margin-top: 5px;
    }
ul.breaks{
    margin:36px;
    margin-left: -24px !important;
margin-right: 101px !important;
    margin-top: 4px !important; 
    }
.dtext{
    font-size:10px;
        }

/*.buttons-size{

    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -webkit-appearance: none; 
}
*/
}
/* ----------- iPad mini ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
      div .fixed{
              width: 41% !important;
          }
#container{
        height: 43.2% !important;   
    }
.white-overlay{
    top: 35.2% !important;
        }
div#closetip{
    margin-top: -25px !important;
    }
.atail{
        margin-top: -12px !important;
    }
.manualtooltip{
    top:5% !important;
    height:25.5% !important;
    }
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
      div .fixed{
              width: 41% !important;
          }
#container{
        height: 43.2% !important;   
    }
.white-overlay{
    top: 35.2% !important;
        }
div#closetip{
    margin-top: -25px !important;
    }
.atail{
        margin-top: -12px !important;
    }
.manualtooltip{
    top:5% !important;
    height:25.5% !important;
    }
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
      #container{
                height: 64.2% !important;
          }
.white-overlay{
        top: 56.2% !important;
             }
.manualtooltip{
        width: 372px !important;
        top: 21% !important;   
        height: 31% !important;
    }
div#closetip{
        padding-left: 296px !important;
    }
.atail{
        margin-top: -7px !important;
    }
}
/* ----------- iPad 3 and 4 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
div .fixed {
    /*top: 32%;*/
    margin-right: 16px;

}
.white-overlay{
    top:32%;
    }
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
div .fixed {
    /*top: 32%;*/
    margin-right: 16px;

}

.white-overlay{
    top:32%;
    }
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
div .fixed {
    /*top: 58%;*/
    margin-right: 16px;

}
.white-overlay{
    top:58%;
    }
}
@media  screen and (min-width: 1140px) {
    .atail{
        margin-top:-8px ;       
        }
    div .fixed{
        width: 32% ;
        }
    .white-overlay{
        top: 52% !important;
        }
    }



/* (1920x1080) Full HD Display */
@media  screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    /* insert styles here */
    div .fixed {
    /*top:61%;*/
    left:76%;
    width:23% !important;
}
.white-overlay{
    top: 55.2% !important ;
    }
.manualtooltip{
    top:32% !important; 
    width: 21% !important;
    height:19% !important;
    }
p#manualtip{
    font-size:16px !important;
    margin-right:20px !important;
    margin-top:13px !important;

    }
.kicker{
    font-size:15px !important;
    margin-bottom:15px !important;
    margin-left:37px !important;

    }
div#closetip{
    padding-left: 331px !important;
    margin-top:-38px !important;

    }
.atail{
        margin-right: 24px !important;
        margin-top:-4px !important;
        }
#container {
height: 64.2%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:1280px) {
    div .fixed{
        width:26% ;
        }
    .atail{
            margin-top: 3px;    
        }
    .white-overlay{
        top:51.5% ;
        }
    }
/* (1680x1050) WSXGA+ Display */
@media  screen and (min-width: 1680px) {
    /* insert styles here */
}

/* (1440x900) WXGA+ Display */
@media  screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    /* insert styles here */
    div .fixed{
        /*top:80%;*/
        }
    .white-overlay{
        top:80%;
        }   
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
div.tooltip {
    color: #222;
    background: #f0f1f2;
    padding: .5em;
    text-shadow: #f5f5f5 0 1px 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #a6a6a6;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
/*.whats{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#808080;
    padding-left:75%;



    }

.tooltips {
  top:-80px;
  left:20px;
  color: #222; 
  background: #f0f1f2; 
  padding: .5em; 
  text-shadow: #f5f5f5 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 2px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #a6a6a6; 
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
  transition:  opacity 0.5s;
}
.whats:hover .tooltips{
    opacity:1;
}*/



.graticule {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #bbb;
    stroke-width: 0px;
    stroke-opacity: .5;

}
.equator {
    stroke: #f0f1f2;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
.kicker {
    font-size:13px ;
    color:black;
    margin-left: 38px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom:19px;
}
.breaks {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.breaks li {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 16%;
}
.breaks .bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
li {
    line-height: 20px;
}
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.c1 {
    background-color:#98c6e9;
}
.c2 {
    background-color:#4ba8ee;
}
.c3 {
    background-color:#2199f4;
}
.c4 {
    background-color:#268cd9;
}
.c5 {
    background-color:#197ac2;
}
.c6 {
    background-color:#056ab5;
}
.dtext {
    color:black;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top:2px;
}
#tooltip3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 185px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index:10001;
    background-color: white;
    opacity:0.8;
    /*border-color:#2A0000;
    border: 1px solid;
*/   /* -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;*/
   /* -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -mox-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rbga(0, 0, 0, 0.4) pointer-events: none;*/

}

#tooltip3.hidden3 {
    visibility:hidden;

}
#tooltip3 p {

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;

    padding:1px;
    /*text-align:left;*/
}

/*img{
    widht:100px;
    height:100px;   
    position:relative;
    }*/

/*.tooltipp{
      position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -mox-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rbga(0, 0, 0, 0.4) pointer-events: none;
    }*/

p#manualtip{
    font-size:13px ;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:13px;


    color:#056ab5;
    }
p#manualtip:hover{
    cursor:pointer; 
    }
.manualtooltip{
    z-index:11;
    background-color:white;
    right:0;
    top:18%;
    margin-right:10px;
    opacity:0.9;

    padding:10px;


    width: 271px;
    height: 28%;


    margin-bottom:10px;
    visibility:hidden;
    background-color:white;
        }
div#closetip{
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 195px;

    }
div#closetip:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    }
.atail {
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;

    border-width: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cccccc transparent transparent transparent;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-right:33px;
    right:0;

}

.atail2 {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 19px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-right:33px;
    right:0;
}
div#zoombutton{
    right:0;
    margin-right:20px;
    z-index:10;
    top:4%;

    }
/*button#zoom_in{

    text-align:center;
    }
button#zoom_out{
    text-align:center;

    }*/
.buttons-size{


    width:3em;
    height:3em;


    }
p#manualparatip{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
/*input, textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}*/

/*html[xmlns*=""]:root .buttons-size  {  

     }*/


/*@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {*/
    /* Safari and Chrome, if Chrome rule needed */
   /* .someClass {
     color:#c00;
    }*/
    /* Safari 5+ ONLY */
    /*.buttons-size {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
}*/
.white-overlay{
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 100%;
    top: 51.2%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 10%;
    }
.readmore{
font-style: italic;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:100 !important;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.couplename{
    font-size:16px;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
.couplestate{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:100 !important;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ive had a look on my laptop, played with window size and looked on my iphone too, it renders ok on the phone but the map needs scrolling. Is this what you are seeing and what is it you are after?

Comment: everything is fine just adjust `white overlay div` in your `code` for specific sizes.

Comment: Currently I'm using the media queries with !important tag in CSS file, but not sure if this is a good practice. Also, its only displaying ok some of the device. I want to target  Tablets, Large desktop and phones (landscape view). Also, there are few issues across the browsers as well. Please suggest me how shall I make it view perfectly on maximum screen size and broswers.
Thanks

Comment: @Hashy Please view the CSS file, and let me know how to target most of the browser, and please have a look at the index key and manual closing tooltip on "What is this text" which appears weird on different screen.

Thanks

Comment: You will get better results if you add a bit of code here as well.

Comment: @jerseyetr Please refer to this CSS code, and let me know in case you have any solution to this issue. Thanks

Comment: @Deepanshu just set `.white-overlay div width:100%` only for small screens and set `div manualtooltip fixed2` according height and width of screen. also give boarder so that you can see it perfect on mobile devices.

Comment: @Hashy shall I use the !important tag to enforce this functionality on mobile device?

Comment: @Deepanshu it depends on which properties you dont want to alter. Put !important tag only on those properties also in mobile devices to see your map user have to zoom in but they cant scroll vertically and horizontally after zooming in to watch other parts of map. Instead of putting a zoom in and out button use something pinch in and out with free move to any part of map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this,

1. make `"What is this text" <p> tag's width fixed near 70px`
2. then set `.white-overlay width:100%` in all mobile devices which screens are small.
3. adjust `div manualtooltip fixed2` for small devices and give border so it looks fine in mobile devices.